# How to disable metacharacters within regex?

Tags: regex, c++11, boost

In Perl, we can do this

```
$str =~ /\d{3}\Q(a.o.e).u.i.y\E\w+/;
```

where, between `\Q` and `\E`, `(a.o.e).u.i.y` is a literal string within which all metacharacters such as parentheses and dots are all treated as literal characters. What is the counterpart syntax for C++11's regex or Boost's regex? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

No, C++ regex doesn't support \Q and \E escape sequence. You'll need to manually escape all special characters which have special meaning in regex. in your example, you'll need to escape (, ) and .

you can rewrite above regex in C++ 11 as

```
std::regex re(R"(\d{3}\(a\.o\.e\)\.u\.i\.y\w+)");
```

Comment: It's not flexible, though doable. For instance, if the pattern contains a filename, what shall we do? We'll probably have to parse and convert the filename first. It's just too troublesome and tedious. There's indeed a C++ library that offers Perl-like regex. I just dug into my old notebooks and found boost::regex has the perl mode. In fact, it's its default setting. So, problem solved. It supports \Q and \E. Sorry for the noise.